# Mustangs and Messerschmitts Rules

Tags: untagged

I am looking for a copy of the rules to a long since gone game called Mustangs and Messerschmitts. Does anyone have a source to the rules?

Comment: Synopsis at https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1712093/rule-synopsis-and-review

Answer (score 2):

Available for sale in PDF form from https://www.wargamevault.com/product/219901/Mustangs-and-Messerschmitts